# Reusing tests from one HTTP client to another

Tags: unit-testing, architecture, integration-testing

I wrote a simple library in Java that converts HTTP requests from one library (REST-assured) to curl commands. Surprisingly, there were many corner cases of HTTP protocol that I had to support. That led to creating quite a nice suite of tests.

Now I would like to provide support for another format of HTTP requests (Apache HTTP client).

I would like to reuse existing tests to drive development because on abstract level tests would use same HTTP requests that I used for REST-assured. However, the difference would be in their representation:

```
Some abstract HTTP request -> RestAssuredRequest -> library -> curl command

Some abstract HTTP request -> Apache HttpRequest -> library -> curl command
```

In other word, to reuse same tests, I would need first to define some common representation for HTTP request and then converters from this representation to specific HTTP client. Seems like a bit of over-engineering, probably error-prone logic that I would use only in tests. There is already something like that, called [Google HTTP client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client) that is a wrapper over popular HTTP clients, although it does not support REST-assured, which means I would need to provide a support for that.

Am I doomed to the solution where I repeat same tests for each HTTP client I want to support?

Or there is third solution?